# Не могу найти метод в numpy / scipy / sklearn

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

`I` - единичная матрица
`L` - Laplace table

```
|L - X*I| = 0
```

Нужно найти `X`.

Comment: приведите пример входных матриц и матрицы `X` для проверки потенциального решения...

Comment: `||` это детерминант? Какие ограничения на `L`, `X` есть?

Answer (score 1):

По определению единичной матрицы:

```
X*I == X
```

поэтому уравнение может быть приведено к виду:

```
|L - X| = 0
```

если `|...|` - это определитель матрицы, то одним из возможных решениий будет транспонированная матрица `L`, т.к. при транспонировании матрицы ее определитель не изменяется:

```
X = L.T
```

[Здесь можно посмотреть другие свойства определителя матрицы ...](http://portal.tpu.ru/SHARED/k/KONVAL/Sites/Russian_sites/2/05.htm)

Comment: а если `X` это скаляр?

Comment: @jfs, это налагает определенные условия на `L`. В общем случае - решения не будет если `X` должен быть скаляром (хотя в вопросе об этом не сказано).

Comment: да вопрос неясный, может это задача на собственные значения (X скаляр, || - детерминант)